# Help to fix a short tikz chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to do a chart with tikz, I get this

[image: tikz chart]

This is the latex script:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
%%%<
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]]
  \node {Solvatación}
    child {{ node {Implícito} }
        child{ node {Cosmo} }}
    child {{ node {Explícito+Implícito}
      child { node {Solvateshell + Cosmo}
      child { node {Packmol + Cosmo} } }}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I need this:

[image: image2]

Comment: Don't you get a compilation error?

Comment: Yes, but it produces the image anyway, isn't it? @cfr

Comment: It produces an image, but it's not necessarily the correct one. You should always make sure your code doesn't throw any errors, even if the output by accident looks OK.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am sorry

Comment: No need to be sorry, I wasn't angry or anything. It was just advice really. Errors mean that something is wrong, and it's in your best interest to fix them, because you can't be sure that the output you get is the output you intended to get.

Comment: If you can't fix them, then ask a question which includes the text of the error message, as well as the code, and (almost always) somebody can tell you how to fix it. When you get an image anyway, it means TeX tries to carry on by guessing what might have been meant e.g. it adds something or removes something. That often gets the compilation to succeed, but, as @TorbjørnT. says, it is often not with the intended results ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is strange that you don't mention errors, as I get a compilation error with your code. Since you don't say, I don't know if this is the problem or not but I think you have too many curly brackets.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  edge from parent/.append style={->}
  ]
  \node {Solvatación}
  child {
    node {Explícito+Implícito}
    child {
      node {Solvateshell\\+ Cosmo}
    }
    child {
      node {Packmol\\+ Cosmo}
    }
  }
  child {
    node {Implícito}
    child {
      node {Cosmo}
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: fewer curly brackets for more tree]

Personally, I'd use Forest.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  },
  [Solvatación
    [Explícito+Implícito
      [Solvateshell + Cosmo]
      [Packmol + Cosmo]
    ]
    [Implícito
      [Cosmo]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest solution]

However, it certainly isn't necessary here.

Comment: Great! Is possible to add "arrows" instead of "lines" conecting the blocks?a

Comment: @HernanMiraola For arrow tips in the first example, add `edge from parent/.append style={->,>=stealth}` to the `tikzpicture` options.

Comment: I did that, but It doesn't work..@TorbjørnT.

Comment: @HernanMiraola Please see above. (It has arrows now.) If you want a different arrow tip, set it as  Torbjørn T. suggests or use the now recommended `arrows.meta` library and `-Stealth` or `-Latex` or whatever.

Comment: @HernanMiraola It does work. I was posting exactly that change while  Torbjørn T. was commenting, I think.

Comment: You are right I put an extra bracket. Thanks both @cfr

Comment: Incredibly it is not working. It returns `  Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.20 };
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.`

Comment: @HernanMiraola Do you mean it doesn't work in your real document or that precisely my code doesn't work in a new `.tex` file? If the former, have you tried loading the `babel` Ti*k*Z library, as I saw you'd updated your question to load Babel with Spanish. I think that enables short-hands, which cause Ti*k*Z problems. The `babel` library addresses that issue.

Comment: @HernanMiraola That is, add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` in your preamble.

Comment: And is there any solution to use forest? (It worked for tikz, thanks).

Comment: @HernanMiraola Doesn't that work for Forest too? I'd assume it would.

Comment: No, it returns a similar error: `! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.16 \end{forest}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?`

Comment: I have made a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388093/problems-when-using-forest-with-mwe

Comment: In some hours I will have tex 2017 finally installed on debian. I can try what we were talking about, if not mistaken. Isn't it?

Comment: The fix I posted for Forest should work. @HernanMiraola The package author looked it over, I think.

Comment: Yes, I am not talking about this post but there was something you wanted to try with spanish language, maybe I am confused

Comment: @HernanMiraola Yes. My answer to the other question, I think.